# Strings can not be converted to DAO Receiver

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, dao

I am trying to perform batch insertion operation with a list object but while inserting I am getting String cannot be converted to DAO.The receiver in the iterator loop.

I have tried to list the list object, at that time it is printing values from the list. but, when I use generics are normal list it is showing error and I don't find any solution to insert 
From this method I am reading the excel file and storing into list

```
public List collect(Receiver rec)
    {
        //ReadFromExcel rd = new ReadFromExcel();
        List<String> up = new ArrayList<String>();
        //List<String> details = rd.reader();
        //System.out.println(details);
        try( InputStream fileToRead = new FileInputStream(new File(rec.getFilePath()))) 
        { 
            XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileToRead);


            wb.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
            String data ="";
            for(int sn = 0;sn<wb.getNumberOfSheets()-2;sn++)
            {
                sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sn);
                for(int rn =sheet.getFirstRowNum();rn<=sheet.getLastRowNum();rn++)
                {
                    Row row = sheet.getRow(rn);
                    if(row == null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("no data in row ");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(int cn=0;cn<row.getLastCellNum();cn++)
                        {
                            Cell cell = row.getCell(cn);
                            if(cell == null)
                            {
//                                System.out.println("no data in cell ");
//                                data = data + " " + "|";

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String cellStr = fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
                                data = data + cellStr + "|";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            up = Arrays.asList(data.split("\\|"));


           // System.out.println(details);             
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
                {
                Logger.getLogger(BImplementation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } 
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(BImplementation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 

        Iterator iter = up.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(iter.next());
        }

        String row="";
        Receiver info = null;
        String cid = "";
        String cname = "";
        String address = "";
        String mid = "";
        boolean b = false;


        List<Receiver> res = new ArrayList<Receiver>();
        int c = 0;
        try
        {
            String str = Arrays.toString(up.toArray()); 
           //System.out.println(str);
            String s = "";
            s = s + str.substring(1,str.length());
          // System.out.println("S:"+s);
            StringTokenizer sttoken = new StringTokenizer(s,"|");
            int count = sttoken.countTokens();
            while(sttoken.hasMoreTokens())
            {  
                if(sttoken.nextToken() != null)
                {
//                    System.out.print(sttoken.nextToken());
                    cid = sttoken.nextToken();
                    cname = sttoken.nextToken();
                    address = sttoken.nextToken();
                    mid = sttoken.nextToken();


                info = new Receiver(cid,cname,address,mid);
                res.add(info);
               System.out.println("cid :"+cid+ "  cname : "+cname +"  address : "+address+" mid : "+mid);
                c = res.size();
            // System.out.println(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;

                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
           // System.out.println("s");



        } 
            catch(NoSuchElementException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("No Such Element Found Exception" +ex);
            }
        return up;

        }
```

with this method I'm trying to insert into database

```
public boolean insert(List res) 
    {
        String sqlQuery = "insert into records(c_id) values (?)";
        DBConnection connector = new DBConnection();

        boolean flag = false;

//        Iterator itr=res.iterator();
//        while(it.hasNext())
//        {
//            System.out.println(it.next());
//        }
         try( Connection con = connector.getConnection();)
         {
             con.setAutoCommit(false);        
             PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);

              Iterator it = res.iterator();
              while(it.hasNext())
              {
                Receiver rs =(Receiver) it.next();
                pstmt.setString(1,rs.getcID());            
                pstmt.setString(2,rs.getcName());
                pstmt.setString(3,rs.getAddress());
                pstmt.setString(4,rs.getMailID());
                pstmt.addBatch();  


              }      
              int [] numUpdates=pstmt.executeBatch();
              for (int i=0; i < numUpdates.length; i++) 
              {
                if (numUpdates[i] == -2)
                {
                  System.out.println("Execution " + i +": unknown number of rows updated");
                  flag=false;
                }
                else
                {
                  System.out.println("Execution " + i + "successful: " + numUpdates[i] + " rows updated");
                  flag=true;
                }
              }
              con.commit();
            } catch(BatchUpdateException b) 
            {
              System.out.println(b);
              flag=false;
            }       
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            { 
                Logger.getLogger(BImplementation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                System.out.println(ex);
                flag=false;
            }
return flag;      
        }
```

I want to insert list object using JDBC batch insertion to the database.

Comment: a String is not a Receiver of any kind. that error message is perfectly clear about why it is thrown.

Comment: Generics exist since Java 5 and allow to have type-safe collections. Java 5 came out in 2004. We're in 2019, 15 years later, and you still use raw List type, and thus obviously get runtime exceptions because of that. Don't use raw types. If the list is supposed to be a List of Receiver, then its type should be `List<Receiver>`, not `List`. And it shoud be named `receivers`, not `res`.

Comment: What objects do you store in the list? When you do the cast operation *(Receiver) it.next();* it expects that this element from list is a Receiver object.

Comment: Please add the code where you create this list.

Comment: @Reynard i updated the code please check once

Comment: @Stultuske i know that i did mistake there that's why i am asking your help to find the solution

Comment: the solution is: "don't try to cast an instance of String to an instance of DAO Receiver".

Comment: @Stultuske if i don't typecast it is showing the error as object can not be converted as Receiver and if i don't typecast it to Receiver how can i add to database columns separately

Comment: you should start learning from the basics. There is no hierarchical relationship between Receiver and String, so it is in no way possible to directly cast them. You could build one, based on the String you get, but that's an entire different matter

Answer (score 0):

Your method *collect(Receiver rec)* returns the List of strings called **up**.

```
return up;
```

However (if you are really using the method *collect* to pass the List into *insert(List res)* method), you are expecting this list to contain Receiver objects. Which is incorrect, since it collect(..) returns the list of Strings.

And that causes an error when you try to cast *Receiver rs =(Receiver) it.next();*

**You need to review and fix your code, so you will pass the list of Receiver objects instead of strings.**

And I really recommend you to start using Generics wherever you use List class. In this case compiler will show you all data-type errors immediately.